# Load a website in a specific data-section after press submit

Tags: php, forms, captcha

There is the problem:

I have a website that contains all the sections in just a page, so it is large website, I have a formulary with a reCaptcha almost at the buttom of the website, so when people don't enter the good captcha and press submit it loads the website again but it goes to the top of the website  so people get lost becouse they don't know if the mail was sended or what as they have to scroll down for see the warning message that they didn't put the correct captcha.

The question, is there a way that when they press the submit it loads the website in a specific section? in this case "menu3" section

This is what I have:

```
<section  id="menu3"> </section>

      <form action="?done=1" method="post" name="myphpform" id="myphpform"   >
      <input type="text" id="nombre" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre"  required value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['nombre'])) { echo $_POST['nombre']; } ?>" />
      <input type="text" id="telefono" class="form-control" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono y/o celular"   value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['telefono'])) { echo $_POST['telefono']; } ?>" />
      <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Escribe tu e-mail"  required   value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['email'])) { echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" />
      <textarea name="comentarios"   id="comentarios"  class="form-control"   placeholder="Comentarios y/o preguntas" required  /><?php if (!empty($_POST['comentarios'])) { echo $_POST['comentarios']; } ?></textarea>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Enviar" />
      </form>
```

and the php:

```
<?php
            @require_once('recaptchalib.php');
            $publickey = "";
            $privatekey = "";
            $resp = null;
            $error = null;
            if ($_POST["submit"]) {
           $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                              $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                              $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                              $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
                              if ($resp->is_valid) {
                              $to="mail@mail";
                              $subject="Contacto";
                              $body="Contacto:
                              Nombre: " .$_POST["nombre"] . "\n
                              Empresa: " .$_POST["empresa"] . "\n
                              Ubicacion: " .$_POST["ubicacion"] . "\n
                              Telefono: " .$_POST["telefono"] . "\n
                              E-mail: " .$_POST["email"] . "\n
                              Comentarios: " .$_POST["comentarios"] . "\n"; 
                              mail($to,$subject,$body, null, '-fmail@mail.mx');
                              $resultMenuUrlName = "contacto_gracias.html";
                              echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=0;URL=$resultMenuUrlName>";
                              exit(1);
                              } else {
                                  echo "Lo sentimos pero no ha colocado el texto correctamente! Intente nuevamente...";
                                  }
                              }
                              echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
                              ?>
```

thx in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a named anchor:

then make the url: http://myurl.com#value

Comment: thx, it works, but is there another way to make it?
I ask becouse my website have some effects that use java script at the beginning, so it only works  if i take out all the effects :(

Answer (score 0):

well I finally found how to go to the section after all the website is loaded as at the beginning my site have a little animation, maybe is not the best solution but it works for me. I just add it to the php:

```
echo "<script type=''>
setTimeout(function() {
window.location = '#anchor';
}, 7000);
</script>";
```